# Apollo 'Like' hooks for doing rest api queries

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo

I recently came across Apollo in Wes Bos's advanced react tutorial. I loved the single hook + caching mechanism. I also like graphql but I have a project that is not using graphql. Are there any packages out there that have a single hook that returns data, error, and loading like the useQuery hook in Apollo? I found this really slick and useful and would like to have something like this in other projects when dealing with REST APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert your Rest API to graphql, checkout the datasource section in the apollo server documentation.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data-sources/

still If you want to use Rest API, Checkout the react-query library.
https://react-query.tanstack.com/
It does caching and queries similar to apollo graphql and also has many more feature.